# Siri seems to usually have network issues. Fix?

Tags: siri

iPhone 4S: at first, Siri was magical. In the last 3-4 days she usually reports an inability to work due to network issues. I've tried myriad fixes but to no avail. Anyone have ideas?

Comment: Siri is neither male or female.

Answer (score 1):

[Siri](http://www.apple.com/iphone/features/siri-faq.html) is still in beta (as of today, 11 December 2011). If you have no trouble accessing other network services on your iPhone 4S, assume that the fault is on Apple's end.